# Ag Grid not displaying column values for which grouping by row is enabled angular 8

Tags: angular, grouping, ag-grid

I am working with Ag-Grid version 21.1.0 and Angular 8. I am trying row-grouping in ag-grid following the tutorial: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/ I have a field in my data-model as "Short Name" field and I am trying to group by this field by setting "rowGroup"="true" property of corresponding column-def object. A new column called "Group" is created in the Ag-grid but the values for this newly created column are not displayed by the grid.[image]
I am using server side filtering and sorting for the grid and using rowmodeltype="infinite". Kindly help me where I am going wrong.

Update:
I am creating a list of column Metadata Objects dynamically. For the specific column by which I want to group the data, I am setting the
following attributes:

```
  columnMetaObj.rowGroup = true;
  columnMetaObj.enableRowGroup = true;
  columnMetaObj.hide = true;
```

then finally I am setting grid options as follows:

```
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = this.gridColDataInput.columnDefs;
    this.gridOptions.rowModelType = 'infinite';
    this.gridOptions.cacheBlockSize = 100;
    this.gridOptions.paginationPageSize = 100;
```

Comment: Can you show the code that will be helpful to understand what you are doing?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: No I haven't found

Answer (score 1):

The behavior that you describe is the default behavior for the grid.
To keep the columns visible when they are added to a group, 
specify `suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns=true` in your gridOptions.

This is documented part-way down the page at the link that you referenced, along with an example, at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#keepingColumnsVisible

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. Please try to add the below changes in your css/scss file.

```
.ag-group-value {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `valueFormatter`, `comparator` or other grid option functions please add a debugger on those functions and check for errors.
I also faced a similar kind of situation and the error was occurring in the comparator function and it was not visible in the browser console.